# Reduce data on the fly in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am rendering an SVG using D3 that shows circles from JSON data. I want to support zooming and dragging. The JSON structure can get very large. Here is my main issue:

- Appending circles for all JSON entries doesn't really work. The page becomes way too slow as there might be thousands of `<circle>` elements in the DOM.

How I'm solving it:

- I keep a reduced copy of the data set that I update in the drag function. On each dragging event, I declare an empty data set:

`var reducedData = [];`

I go over the entire data set and only push to `reducedData` the circles that have center coordinates that are visible given the current axis. I then erase the SVG and redraw it using `reducedData`. I do the same process on every zoom event, only appending to `reducedData` the circles that have a radius greater than 5 pixels given the current zoom ratio.

Although page is very responsive and seems to work well, it's very inefficient and I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this. What are some alternative solutions to my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [*"Render only SVG nodes of data that is currently visible?"*](/q/34653293).

Comment: Sounds like you want want to ditch `svg` and move to a `canvas` based [visualization](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/d1f7b58631e71fbf9c568345ee04a60e).

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's always room for improvement, but I think that your approach is already good enough and may it doesn't get so much better than that. However here are some points for you to consider and/or test by yourself if you wish so...

First off I would recommend you to check if any optimization is really needed. In latest versions of Google Chrome, in its DevTools under the "performance" tab, you can use CPU throttling to simulate a slower device. Then using the [timeline tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool), you can verify if either your data reduction or DOM manipulations are causing any bottlenecking and dropping your frame rate. If not, don't sweat it, you're good to go.

If from your analysis, you find that the data reduction is slowing down your rendering, you can use the timeline tool to find exactly where it is slow and research for faster alternatives.

In the other hand if it is your DOM manipulation that is causing any trouble, make sure that you're using the [general update pattern](https://www.dashingd3js.com/lessons/d3-basic-general-update-pattern) which ensures that you're creating or removing elements only when really needed. Furthermore you may speed up the creation of circles by [duplicating them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) instead of creating new ones.

Usually when too many data items needs to be visualized, as a last resort we switch from SVG to a canvas based visualization, but I think that would be overkill for your context.

Hope it helps and let us know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Crossfilter.js for fast filtering of the data. That way I don't need to manually keep a reduced copy of the data set. I can simply filter it quickly on each drag and zoom event. Thank you for everyone that answered.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this issue was to only update visible svg elements as the user is panning/zooming.

```
function pointInDomain(d, domain) {
    return d.x < domain[1] && d.x > domain[0]
}

function zoomed() {
  xz = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
  xGroup.call(xAxis.scale(xz));

  var domain = xz.domain();

  clippedArea.selectAll("circle")
    .style("visibility", d => pointInDomain(d, domain) ? "visible" : "hidden")
    .filter(d => pointInDomain(d, domain))
    .attr("cx", d => xz(d.x));
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simonbleier/62ufqbbq/)